# Sorting array of objects by 2 attributes of date

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` of `CoreData` objects, inside I have 2 attributes: month and year. I want to sort the array by years then by months.

`DbDate 1:
month: 04
year: 2010`

`DbDate 2:
month: 04
year: 2012`

`DbDate 3:
month: 06
year: 2011`

`DbDate 4:
month: 05
year: 2015`

I want to sort them to be inside the array:

`DbDate 1
DbDate 3
DbDate 2
DbDate 4`

How could I do that?

Comment: You could start by reading the documentation for NSArray.

Comment: What, the documentation?  It tells you all the things you can do with an NSArray.

Comment: I know the sorting methods that NSArray holds, my problem is that I just can't figure out how to do it and which one is right for this issue. I'm asking for help because I don't know, not because I'm lazy. If you don't feel like helping, that's fine.

Comment: The easiest to use, in terms of the amount you need to learn to use it, is probably `sortedArrayUsingFunction`.  (It's also likely the fastest, or at least nearly so.)  You write a simple C function to define the comparisons you want to do.

Comment: (Try something and show us what you tried.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // If you have an array:
NSArray *arrayOfObject;

NSSortDescriptor *sortByYear = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"year" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByMonth = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"month" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorts = @[sortByYear, sortByMonth];

NSArray *orderedArray = [arrayOfObject sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorts];

// If you want fetch the object ordered, from Core Data.
NSFetchRequest  *yourFetchReques = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Set your entity...
[yourFetchReques setSortDescriptors:sorts];
// .... Your code to make the request...
```